# What is "/admin/Y-ivrrecording.php?php=info&ip=uname"?

Tags: web-server, hacking, web-crawler

Help me please, I found an IP address from Korea try to do something with my web server by put  this '/admin/Y-ivrrecording.php?php=info&ip=uname' like search a filename from my web server. I don't know any reason and any knowledge about this. i try to search info about it on google, but i found nothing to make me know more.

So what is it?, use for what? and Do it harm to my web server?

Comment: What was the response returned by the server (404)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it is a usual bot, that searches some vulnerabilities on sites engine to get access for any server. 
If you're a good administrator and do not forget about security updates, there is nothing to worry about. 
For example, you can look at sshd log with standart 22 port on any public machine: there are tonnes messages that smbd trying to get access to machine.

Welcome to the Internet.